# What moves can grab?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Besides using a grab, some moves (all I know specials) can also initate a "grab", continuing the move through a counter, block, or super armor. I know of Ganon's Side + Special, Bowsers Side + Special, and Lucarios Side + Special, but are there any others?

Comment: Do you count Kirby and Dedede's inhale as a grab?  What's the scope of the question, anything that counts as a sort of command grab?

Comment: That works, as long as they ignore counters and blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to SmashWiki](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Grab#Special_attacks_as_grabs), the Special Attacks that can act as Grabs are:

- Yoshi

  - Neutral, [Egg Lay](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Egg_Lay)
- Kirby

  - Neutral, [Inhale](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Inhale#Kirby)
- Captain Falcon

  - Upper, [Falcon Dive](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Falcon_Dive)
- Bowser

  - Side, [Flying Slam](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Flying_Slam)
- Ganondorf

  - Side, [Flame Choke](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Flame_Choke)
  - Upper, [Dark Dive](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Dark_Dive)
- Wario

  - Neutral, [Chomp](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Chomp)
- King Dedede

  - Neutral, [Inhale](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Inhale#King_Dedede)
- Diddy Kong

  - Side, [Monkey Flip](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Monkey_Flip), though not if an attack button is pressed before he grabs (he will kick instead)
- Lucario

  - Side, [Force Palm](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Force_Palm), but only grounded and at close range
- Robin

  - Down, [Nosferatu](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Nosferatu)
- Mewtwo

  - Side, [Confusion](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Confusion)

I do not believe there are any moves, aside from dedicated Grabs and the aforementioned Specials, that cause a grabbing hitbox (i.e., that ignores shields).